# Nativescript angular new project creating error

Tags: nativescript, new-project

I installed all the environment setups for nativescript angular but I can't create new project using tns create command when I tried it shows me a error like this can anyone pls help me to solve to error 
While trying I got this below error

npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.0: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...":"latest","@types/gu'

Comment: Hi Vimal, could you add what command are you using?

Comment: tns create command

Comment: Now I resolved that error,I used npm cache clean --force command to resolve that issue